# List vs Dictionary Length Difference?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

New to python, but having a bit of trouble with transforming a large list into a dictionary.

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in zipped_list_total for item in sublist]
print(flat_list)
print(len(flat_list)) #result is 9673

ticker_dictionary = dict([(d[0], d[1:]) for d in flat_list])
print(len(ticker_dictionary)) #result is 6396
```

To give you some background, zipped_list_total is a list that appends 3 different zipped lists together into one large zipped list. Flat_list is pretty much just drilling down the zipped list by one level. For example.. len(zipped_list_total) is 3, len(flat_list) is 9673

If we look at flat_list, the data is formatted like such:
 [(a,b,c),(d,e,f).....]

Basically I am trying to make a dictionary that says {a:(b,c), d:(e,f)...}

When I run the code above, it looks like the list correctly transforms into a dictionary up until a certain point, but then stops. Is there a reason why the conversion would stop (does it have something to do with memory?)

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: You likely have duplicate keys.  A dictionary can only store each key once.

Comment: ohhhh you're a smart man - I knew that was a rule, but I didn't think to check it in this scenario. You were right - thank you sir

Comment: I'll make this an answer so you can accept it and close off this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have duplicate keys. A dictionary can only store each key once.